# block-ui-pattern has no effect

Tags: angularjs, blockui, jquery-blockui

i am trying to implement block-ui into our angular application on an element by element basis.  (everything is included, referenced and injected correctly)

1. We have been trying to implement

   ```
   block-ui-pattern
   ```

   with no success.

our $http request is :-

```
 $http.get('/user/123/GetUserAddress/').then(function (data) {
```

and our block-ui-pattern is :-

```
 < div block-ui block-ui-pattern="/^user\/123\/GetUserAddress\$/">
{{address}}
</div>
```

This seems to match the documentation, but is failing to work. Am i missing something fundamental?

2. Our application exposes an isloading flag. initially set to true, and when the $http promise returns, sets this to false.. I realize that it is not in the documentation, however, Is there a way to set

   ```
   < div block-ui="isloading"></div>
   ```

Comment: have you use this one http://angular-block-ui.nullest.com/#!/

Comment: Hi, this is the sample that I was looking at, and unable to get the block ui pattern to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post by Parash Gami pointed me in the right direction. 
I actually ended up writing a custom directive that wraps block-ui

```
var myBlocker = angular.module('app.Angular.Directive.myBlocker ', []);

myBlocker.directive('myBlocker ', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope :{
        blockId: '@id',
        block: '=',
    },
    controller: ['$scope', 'blockUI', function ($scope, blockUI) {
        var myBlock = blockUI.instances.get($scope.blockId);

        $scope.$watch('block', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if ($scope.block === true)
            {
                myBlock.start()
            }
            else {
                myBlock.stop()
            }
        });


    }],
    link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.attr('block-ui', scope.blockId);
        element.attr('style', 'min-height:200px;');
        element.removeAttr("my-blocker"); 
        element.removeAttr("data-my-blocker");
        $compile(element)(scope);
    }
};
```

}]);

This allows me to now simply add the directive to an element

```
< div id="myId" my-blocker block="loading">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check sample code. Just include one CSS and one JS of blockUI and add dependency blockUI, use blockUI.start() method to show loader and use blockUI.stop() method to hide loader. Following example hide loader after 2 seconds. Use it as per your requirement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-block-ui.nullest.com/angular-block-ui/angular-block-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-block-ui.nullest.com/angular-block-ui/angular-block-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app.user">
    <div ng-controller="tempController">
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('app.user',['blockUI']);
    app.controller('tempController', function(blockUI,$timeout)
    {
        blockUI.start();
        $timeout(function()
        {
            blockUI.stop();
        },2000)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the replay. Really wanted to use the block-ui-pattern though..  One thing i have just noticed, is that the block-ui-pattern actually works only when autoblock is switched on.. this cant be right can it?

Comment: i cannot understand you.